# access txt file without cause IOException to another application

Tags: c#, system.io.file

It seems another application writes lines to a txt file as the same time my application reads its lines so another application throws an message as below. Then it doesn't write lines anymore.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5UaR.jpg)

I don't it to stop writing new lines so I try copy the file to different place then read it.

```
string myFilePath = Function.log_reflow + @"\" + today + ".Log";
            if (File.Exists(myFilePath))
            {
                haveFile = true;
            }
            else
            {
                string yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("MM-dd-yy");
                myFilePath = Function.log_reflow + @"\" + yesterday + ".Log";
                if (File.Exists(myFilePath))
                {
                    haveFile = true;
                }
            }
            if (haveFile == true)
            {
                string tempDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\tempReflow.txt";
                File.Copy(myFilePath, tempDir, true);

                //read file
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(tempDir);}
```

But the message still shows. Are there any solutions to do my work without cause problem to another application ?

Comment: Another application should share the file with read access. [FileShare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare?view=net-5.0)

Comment: I can't do anything to another application. What I can do is changing mine. Do Exist or Copy method opened the file that make another application can't write ?